# Was bedeutet “angezeckt”?

Tags: meaning, slang

Ich habe die Bedeutung dieses Wortes nicht herausgefunden.
Kann jemand mir helfen? Ein Beispiel auf Englisch wäre super.

> Die Nacht ist vorbei, die bösen Geister sind weg Ich kipp’ dich aus’m Bett und mach Kaffee der tote Tanten weckt. Sind schön **angezeckt**, löschen unser’n Brand mit Sekt Und fahr’n an Strand – das Leben fiebert.

Comment: Kontext? Vielleicht Verwechslung mit "angezickt" ('bitched at')?

Comment: Ich habe ihn angeschlossen. Es ist ein Teil eines Liedes.

Comment: Theoriefindung: Das Wort bezieht sich auf das Schimpfwort "Zecke", mit dem Punks oft von Rechten bezeichnet werden und wie sich Punks heute ironisch auch selbst bezeichnen. Als (stereo)typisch für Punks gilt der Bierkonsum. 'Angezeckt' könnte heißen, einen Kater zu haben. Der Band Seeed (von der der Text stammt) ist zuzutrauen, dass sie ironisch-kreativ mit dieser Bedeutung von 'Zecke' umgehen.

Comment: Was genau meinst Du mit *einem Beispiel auf Englisch?*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Eine Übersetzung!?

Comment: @Grantwalzer ja, genau. Ich meinte ein englisches Wort, mit dem ich, vielleicht, herauskomme kann.

Comment: @Chris es hat mir geholfen, danke Ihnen!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scheint ein aktueller Songtext zu sein. Eigentlich ist mir "angezeckt"   nicht bekannt, aber vom Kontext her würde ich es als "von zu viel Alkohol angeschlagen oder ganz schön blau" verstehen. Man hat einen "Brand", das heißt ein Bedürfnis nach neuer Alkoholzufuhr, weil der Alkoholspiegel nach kurzem Schlaf gesunken ist, und diesen Brand bekämpft man am besten mit einer neuen Flasche, dann steigt der Alkoholspiegel wieder und man fühlt sich wieder besser.

"angezeckt" scheint mir eine der vielen Varianten für angetrunken zu sein, wie sie in speziellen Gruppen laufend neu erfunden werden.

Comment: "Brand" ist mir als Durst am nächsten Tag bekannt, ugs ;)

Comment: Da dürfte es verschiedene Auffassungen geben. Ich verstehe es mehr in folgendem Sinne: Ein Spiegeltrinker (ein Alkoholiker, der einen bestimmten Alkoholspiegel im Blut hanen muß, damit er sich normal fÜhlt, ohne dass man ihm etwas anmerkt), spürt, wenn sein Alkoholspiegel sinkt, fühlt sich unwohl und muß unbedingt etwas trinken. Er hat einen Brand.

Comment: Ah, auch interessant - diese Bedeutung war mir nicht bekannt, merci für die Erhellung!

Answer (score 1):

Es bedeutet so viel wie aufgeputscht, voller Tatendrang, kann aber, wie schon erwähnt, auch angetrunken (leicht betrunken) heißen.

Answer (score 0):

Already reading the **angezeckt** and the question in the headline and now definitely looking at the aggressive *kicking you out of my bed* I sense this to be no mis-spelled **angezickt** but expressis verbis Neo-Nazi lyrics with the [Zecke](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zecke) being a parasite to be gassed out of the world like all we communist internet libertarians ought to be.  Hence **angezeckt** means something *having been given the usual parasite bullshit*.  German at its worst.

Comment: Looking up the lyrics shows that is comes from Seeed, a Berlin Reggae band. Also, it says "kipp" not "kick" out of bed.

Comment: Entschuldigung aber ich glaube es nicht, dass dieses Wort so eine Bedeutung trägt. In diesem Kontext glaube ich nun weniger. Trotzdem kann ich ja falsch sein. Lies mal die anderen Antworten.

Comment: You're right. I must have misread the lover-like bed tilt and I would also trust Seeed to know more of the latest Berlin slangwords than I do.